# Jenkins plugin to generate kube config for kubectl after changes to kubectl authentication for GKE

Tags: authentication, google-kubernetes-engine, gcloud, kubectl

Since for kubectl to access gke, now gke-gcloud-auth-plugin also needs to be installed.

I am using jenkins to deploy the changes to gke using the kubectl plugin but now after this change, not able to use the same plugin.

Can anyone suggest any jenkins plugin that can help to access gke after this change is rolled out in kubectl.

https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/containers-kubernetes/kubectl-auth-changes-in-gke

Answer (score 0):

You could use `google/cloud-sdk` image, which has `gke-gcloud-auth-plugin` already pre-installed. But now **before** `gcloud container clusters get-credentials` you should run:

```
export USE_GKE_GCLOUD_AUTH_PLUGIN=True
```